# Nested Queries in Realm. Swift

Tags: swift, realm, swift4, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to create nested queries in realm. I will paste my models in and explain what I mean.

**Parent Model**

```
@objcMembers class Group: Object {

    dynamic var uuid: String = ""
    dynamic var admin: User?

    convenience init(uuid: String, admin: User) {
        self.init()
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.admin = admin
    }
}
```

**Child Model**

```
@objcMembers class Message: Object {

    dynamic var uuid: String = ""
    dynamic var group: Group?
    dynamic var message: String = ""

    convenience init(uuid: String, group: Group, from: User, message: String) {
        self.init()
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.group = group
        self.message = message
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is filter messages that are in a group with uuid `x`

All the answers I have seen are outdated.

What I have right now is

`let result = RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Message.self).filter("group.uuid =
0E81CDEF-B63F-4DBE-9900-B486D40F4EC9")`

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Just a thought here; what is the relationship between Parent and Child? i.e. can a parent have multiple children? If so, can you represent that relationship with a List? That would make queries a snap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
let result = RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Message.self).filter("group.uuid = '2C5E1738-1167-40CB-BE43-C415FD5E6E5D'")
```

Queried value has to be wrapped in `''`